# Packaging an "Errors" Skin Update

Tags: theme, xml

What's the right way to package a theme for the `errors` folder?

That is, Magento's serves its 503 page and Store Exception 404 pages out of the following folder

```
errors/*
```

The `errors` folder contains a mini-theming system that ships with a default theme

```
errors/default/
```

and has a `local.xml` system that allows users to change that theme.

```
errors/local.xml.sample
```

I know as an extension developer I can ship a custom theme for `errors` by using a namespaced folder

```
errors/packagename_modulename
```

However, is there anyway for me to activate this by default, short of writing some code to create/replace the `local.xml` file in this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once have to do for a client, I copied the `errors/default` folder and `local.xml.sample` on my local, themed it and changed the name of folder to `mythemed`, renamed the local.xml.sample  to `local.xml` and  just changed the `<skin>default</skin>` to `<skin>mythemed</skin>`, packaged both of them in a folder `errors` and uploaded to his ftp. It worked. If there is any more convenient way and I am sure you will get one, as you are one of the best programmers of Magento, please do share it.